# How to find whether the same customers who ordered this month also ordered the next month?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, window-functions

I have an orders table

```
Order_id  User_id  Order_date
 1        32        2020-07-19
 2        24        2020-07-21
 3        27        2020-07-27
 4        24        2020-08-14
 5        32        2020-08-18
 6        32        2020-08-19
 7        58        2020-08-20
```

Now I want to find how many of the users ordered in 1st month also ordered in the next month. In this case, user_id's 32,24,27 ordered in 7th month but only 24 and 32 ordered in the next month.

I want the result to be like :

```
Date   Retained_Users  Total_users
2020-07     Null            3
2020-08      2              3
```

I'm lost here. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select 
    order_month, 
    count(distinct case when cnt_orders_last_month > 0 then user_id end) retained_users,
    count(distinct user_id) total_users
from (
    select 
        user_id, 
        date_format(order_date, '%Y-%m-01') as order_month,
        count(*) over(
            partition by user_id
            order by date(date_format(order_date, '%Y-%m-01'))
            range between interval 1 month preceding and interval 1 day preceding
        ) cnt_orders_last_month
    from mytable
) t
group by order_month
```

The logic lies in the range specification of the window function; it orders record by month, and counts how many orders the customer placed last month. Then all that is left to do is aggregate and count distinct users.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b582422cd328e5076294a797edcd8f96)**